# Adding Ext.Menu to the viewport in Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I am making a basic application in Sencha Architect 3, and trying to add a menu button in the style of touch-tomatoes http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/touch-build/examples/touchtomatoes/index.html

The code for adding the menu in the Touch Tomatoes project is an addition in the app.js file of Sencha Touch project as below, but I am unable to figure out how to do this in Sencha Architect, as it says that the app.js file would be over-ridden each time the project is saved

Ext.application({
        name: 'TouchTomatoes',

```
    requires: ['Ext.device.Storage','Ext.Menu', 'TouchTomatoes.components.MenuButton'],
    controllers: ['TouchTomatoes.controller.Main'],
    views: ['TouchTomatoes.view.Main', 'TouchTomatoes.view.WelcomeOverlay'],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.getBody().removeCls('loading');
        Ext.create('TouchTomatoes.view.Main');

        if (Ext.device.Storage.getItem('isFirstTime') !== "false") {
            Ext.device.Storage.setItem('isFirstTime', false);

            var overlay = Ext.create('TouchTomatoes.view.WelcomeOverlay');
            Ext.Viewport.add(overlay);
            overlay.show();
        }

        var menu = Ext.create("Ext.Menu", {
            defaults: {
                xtype: "menubutton"
            },
            width: '80%',
            scrollable: 'vertical',
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Opening',
                    iconCls: 'time',
                    menu:"opening"
                },
                {
                    text: 'Theatres',
                    iconCls: 'locate',
                    menu: "theatres"
                },
                {
                    text: 'Upcoming',
                    iconCls: 'team',
                    menu:"upcoming"
                },
                {
                    text: 'Top',
                    iconCls: 'bank',
                    menu:'top'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Search',
                    iconCls: 'search',
                    menu:"search"
                }
            ]
        });

        Ext.Viewport.setMenu(menu, {
            side: 'left',
            reveal: true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have launch defined, so simply paste your two statements within it within architect.

In architect,

- click on **Application** in the inspector
- click on the **launch** action in the config pane to bring it up in the editor (Or, if you don't have launch defined, click on the + icon next to launch in the Config pane to add it.)
- paste your code into the editor beneath your overlay code:

  ```
  var menu = Ext.create("Ext.Menu", {
  defaults: {
          xtype: "menubutton"
      },
      width: '80%',
      scrollable: 'vertical',
      items: [
          {
              text: 'Opening',
              iconCls: 'time',
              menu:"opening"
          },
          {
              text: 'Theatres',
              iconCls: 'locate',
              menu: "theatres"
          },
          {
              text: 'Upcoming',
              iconCls: 'team',
              menu:"upcoming"
          },
          {
              text: 'Top',
              iconCls: 'bank',
              menu:'top'
          },
          {
              text: 'Search',
              iconCls: 'search',
              menu:"search"
          }
      ]
  });

  Ext.Viewport.setMenu(menu, {
      side: 'left',
      reveal: true
  });
  ```

You'll end up with exactly the code you listed above, and it wont be overwritten since it's part of the app's config.

Be aware that, since you include an xtype of 'menubutton,' that you'll have to create a button at the class level and give it a userAlias of 'menubutton,' or the app will throw an error stating, roughly, "I can't create widget with xtype.menubutton."